# Javascript return filtered array inside switch statement

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

What is correct way of doing filter on array inside switch statement

```
let filteredMachines = (filterTerm,filterField) => {
       switch (filterField) {
       case 'NomAppareil':this.props.machines.filter(machine => {
           return machine.nomAppareil === filterTerm;
       });
       break;

       case 'CodeAppareil':this.props.machines.filter(machine => {
           return machine.codeAppareil === filterTerm;
       });
       break;

       case 'NomClient':this.props.machines.filter(machine => {
           return machine.nomClient === filterTerm;
       });
       break;

       case 'CodeClient':this.props.machines.filter(machine => {
            console.log('inside CodeClient ='+JSON.stringify(machine));
           return (machine.codeClient == filterTerm);
       });
       break;

       case 'NoSerie':this.props.machines.filter(machine => {
           return machine.noSerie === filterTerm;
       });
       break;

       default: return this.props.machines;
     }
   };
```

Edit: I found working solution given below

```
let filteredMachines = machines.filter((machine) =>{
     switch (filterField) {
     case 'NomAppareil':  return machine.nomAppareil === filterTerm;
     case 'CodeAppareil': return machine.codeAppareil === filterTerm;
     case 'NomClient': return machine.nomClient === filterTerm;
     case 'CodeClient': return machine.codeClient === filterTerm;
     case 'NoSerie': return machine.noSerie === filterTerm;
           default: return true;
   }
```

});

Comment: what is the main issue? The above code does not work OR you're searching an optimized(refactored) approach ?

Comment: Code is not working

Comment: please add some use cases and the wanted result and the errors you get.

Comment: Why don't you just do `this.props.machines.filter(machine => machine[filterField] === filterTerm);`

Comment: machine is a Json object

Comment: filteredMachines is coming undefined, this.props.machines console prints ok

Answer (score 5):

Basically you need to return the filtered array (hence the `undefined` result), then you can omit the break statement.

```
case 'NomAppareil':
    return this.props.machines.filter(machine => {
//  ^^^^^^
       return machine.nomAppareil === filterTerm;
    });
    // break;
```

Or use [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) instead of the `switch` statement.

```
let filteredMachines = (filterTerm, filterField) => {
    var set = new Set(['NomAppareil', 'CodeAppareil', 'NomClient', 'CodeClient', 'NoSerie']);
    return set.has(filterField)
        ? this.props.machines.filter(machine => machine[filterField] === filterTerm)
        : this.props.machines;
};
```

Comment: The part using the `Set` iterable object is very clever. Well deserved +1 for that.

Comment: i do not know what `this` is referencing and how you object look like. maybe you have to check for existens of the object first if apply the assignment of `filteredMachines`.

Comment: this.props.machines console logs ok with values. Still getting returned undefined.

Comment: could you make a `console.log` of `this.props.machines` inside of `filteredMachines`? as i wrote, `this` may be not this, what you expect inside of an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Answer (score 0):

You might do as follows;

```
var filters = ["NomAppareil","CodeAppareil","NomClient","CodeClient","NoSerie"],
     result = filters.indexOf(filterField) !== -1 ? this.props.machines.filter(machine => machine[filterField] === filterTerm)
                                                  : this.props.machines;
```